# Remove gap between bars

Tags: gnuplot

I have created the Figure 1 in gnuplot, that contains 12 bars in total, with 4 group of bars where each group is composed by 3 bars.
There are 3 things in the graph that I want to change, that I don't know how to do it.

1. I want to remove the small gap that exists between the bars of each sub-group.
2. I would like to have the full bars that are in each end of the graph, instead of having them cut in half.
3. I would like to have just 1 label for each group in the X axis. Eg, instead of having three times 1000 (one subgroup), I just want 1000 written one time. I want one label for each subgroup.

**Figure 1:** Graph that I have
[image: Graph that I have]

**Figure 2:** Graph that I want
[image: Graph that I want]

Here is the data that I am using:

For the first bar (the first bar - blank one)

```
# Size  Average
1000 360.48
2000 545.94
4000 1008.16
8000 1982.56
```

For the second bar (the bar in the middle)

```
# Size  Average
1000 251.37
2000 360.29
4000 646.79
8000 1226
```

For the third bar (the bar at the right in each subgroup)

```
# Size  Average
1000 373.01
2000 555.34
4000 1014.92
8000 1999.20
```

For that values, I have used the following gnuplot script

```
set yrange [ 0 : 2200 ] noreverse nowriteback

set boxwidth 0.25
plot "first-bar.dat"  u ($0-.05):2:2:xtic(1)  w boxerrorbars ls 4 title "First bar", \
     "second-bar.dat" u ($0+0.25):2:2:xtic(1) w boxerrorbars ls 5 title "Second bar", \
     "third-bar.dat"  u ($0+0.55):2:2:xtic(1) w boxerrorbars ls 6 title "Third bar"
```

How I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a real histogram for such a plot, i.e. the `histogram` plotting style:

```
set yrange [0:*]
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1

plot 'first-bar.dat' u 2:xtic(1) ls 4 title 'first',\
     'second-bar.dat u 2 ls 5 title 'second',\
     'third-bar.dat' u 2 ls 6 title 'third'
```